# How to pass value of selection from calendar to input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using a DatePicker component, from the Antd library that's running MomentJS under the hood for date/time functionality, as part of a larger scheduling component.

I've created a second input element within my component that is set to disabled. This is so that the input is read only. I'm trying to pass the value of whatever date is selected from the calendar to that input field in this format: `7/09/2019`

Is there a way to do this at the component level?

[image: Edit goofy-currying-csgtr]

`My Component`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { DatePicker, Row, Col } from "antd";

function onChange(value, dateString) {
  console.log("Selected Time: ", value);
  console.log("Formatted Selected Time: ", dateString);
}

function onOk(value) {
  console.log("onOk: ", value);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Row>
      <Col span={8}>
        <DatePicker
          open
          className="my-class"
          onChange={onChange}
          onOk={onOk}
          format="MMMM"
        />
      </Col>
      <Col span={2} offset={6}>
        <input value="7/09/2019" disabled />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should track the value using state.

You can use the traditional method of defining a class component & using `setState`, or you can use hooks.

As for constructing the date string, there's native JS methods to help you out with this! `Date.toLocaleDateString`

I'd recommend checking out the 'Date' docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { DatePicker, Row, Col } from "antd";

const DatePickerExample = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US"));

  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <DatePicker
            open
            className="my-class"
            onChange={value =>
              setDate(new Date(value).toLocaleDateString("en-US"))
            }
            onOk={value => setDate(new Date(value).toLocaleDateString("en-US"))}
            format="MMMM"
          />
        </Col>
        <Col span={2} offset={6}>
          <input value={date} disabled />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<DatePickerExample />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Here's a CodeSandbox link to the example provided!
https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-paper-hswmo